# Tengo un condicional if que sí ejecuta la condición pero no realiza el codigo o no manda el return que debería

Tags: php, ajax, mvc

necesito me ayuden, pues he regresado a la programación despues de 15 años y me estoy poniendo al día en todo.
Tengo un condicional if que sí ejecuta la condición pero no realiza el codigo o no manda el return que debería. Esta dentro de un metodo, en un Modelo, llamado por el Controlador y solicitado por un Ajax.
Comparto el todo el codigo:

Archivo ordenes.js: Desde acá hago la llamada al archivo php con ajax.

```
$('.QC').on('change', '.numQuanty', function(){

    var idQC     = $(this).attr("IdQC");
    var cantidad = $(this).val();
    var precio   = $(this).attr("precio");
    var ordenId  = $(this).attr("IdO");
    var mesaId   = $(this).attr('mesaId');

    var precioFinal = precio * cantidad;
    precioFinal = parseFloat(precioFinal).toFixed(2);
    $(".pFinal"+idQC).text("Q"+precioFinal);

    var qDatos = new FormData();
    
    qDatos.append('kantidad', cantidad);
    qDatos.append('Total', precioFinal);
    qDatos.append('numQuanty', 'cambiar');
    qDatos.append('idOrden', ordenId);
    qDatos.append('IdPedido', idQC);

        $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/restaurante/Ajax/ordenesA.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: qDatos,
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,

        success: function(resultado){
            swal({
                title: 'Cantidad ha cambiado.',
                type: 'success',
                confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                confirmButtonText: 'Aceptar' 
            }).then(function(resultado){
                if(resultado.value){
                    window.location = "http://localhost/restaurante/index.php?url=Orden&MN="+mesaId+"&Oid="+ordenId;
                }
            });
        }
    });

});
```

Archivo ordenesA.php: Desde acá hago una llamada al metodo que maneja el controlador que hace la consulta.

```
class QuantyChangeA{

    public $kantidad;
    public $idQc;
    public $total;
    public $numQuanty;
    public $idOrden;

    public function numQuantyChange(){
    
        $Q = $this->kantidad;
        $I = $this->idQc;
        $T = $this->total; 
        $O = $this->idOrden;

        $resultado = OrdenesC::cambiarCantidadC($Q, $I, $T, $O);

        if($resultado == true){             

            echo json_encode($resultado);
            
        }
    }


}

/**********************************************/

if(isset($_POST["numQuanty"])){

    $qC = new QuantyChangeA();
    $qC -> kantidad = $_POST["kantidad"];
    $qC -> idQc     = $_POST["IdPedido"];
    $qC -> total    = $_POST["Total"];
    $qC -> numQuanty= $_POST["numQuanty"];
    $qC -> idOrden  = $_POST["idOrden"];
    $qC -> numQuantyChange();
}
```

Archivo ordenesC.php: Acá hago la llamada al metodo que hace un update en la base de datos y espero una respuesta que nunca llega.

```
static public function cambiarCantidadC($Q, $I, $T, $O){

        $tablaBD = 'o_pedidos';

        $resultado = OrdenesM::cambiarCantidadM($tablaBD, $Q, $I, $T);

        if($resultado == true){
            return true;
        } else {
            echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Ejecucion fallida"); </script>';
    }
```

Archivo ordenesM.php: Este es el modelo que hace el update en la base de datos. En el metodo hay un condicional que ejecuta el query para seber si manda respuesta pero allí es donde ya no logro ejecutar el return. Este condicional no hace nada del codigo, ni el 'echo' siquiera.

```
static public function cambiarCantidadM($tablaBD, $Q, $I, $T){

        $pdo = ConexionBD::cBD()->prepare("UPDATE $tablaBD SET cantidad = :cantidad, p_total = :total WHERE id = :id");

        $pdo -> bindParam(":cantidad", $Q, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $pdo -> bindParam(":total", $T, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $pdo -> bindParam(":id", $I, PDO::PARAM_INT);

        if( $pdo -> execute() ){
            echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Ejecutado update");';
            return true;
        } else {
            echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("NO ejecutado update");';
            return false;
        }

    }

#Este es el IF que no funciona. Lo he tratado de varias formas y visto de varios lados y no encuentro nada.
```

Gracias de antemano por su apoyo.

Comment: Veo tres cosas: 1. En `ArchivoControlador` no tienes el `else` cubierto, debes indicar al código qué hacer si el `if` no se cumple.  2. En `ArchivoModelo` devuelves el resultado de la ejecución, el cual sólo es `true` o `false`, pero lo que deberías verificar las filas afectadas. Por ejemplo, una consulta `UPDATE` que no cambia los datos porque el `WHERE` no se cumple o por lo que sea, devolverá `true`, pero ese `true` sólo quiere decir que no hubo error en la ejecución, nada más. 3. En Javascript buscas una clave `value` en la respuesta, pero no veo que devuelvas tal clave desde PHP.

Comment: Gracias A. Cedano, ya cubrí los else y agregue algo de codigo para probar. El problema persiste en que "no se ejecuta nada de lo que supone hacer el IF". Va todo bien de ida, hasta la ejecución del pdo. El condicionla IF es quien ejecuta la consulta pero no realiza el codigo.

Comment: Convendría que muestres cómo recibes la petición en el archivo `ordenesA.php`, pulsa en [edit] para agregar el código que tienes en dicho archivo. Por otra parte, ¿qué haces devolviendo como respuesta un script de Javascript en algunos puntos del programa? No es así como funciona Ajax, debes devolver siempre una respuesta, por ejemplo un array y verificar lo que hay en esa respuesta dentro del `success`, si tú mandas como respuesta código Javascript no tiene ningún sentido, porque Ajax fue creado justamente para evitar esas mezclas y simplificar las cosas.

Comment: El archivo ordenesA.php era el código en ArchivoAjax php. Ya corregí y puse el nombre real a cada código. Perdón por los scripts de javascript. Realmente los puse para ver que saltaran los alert al momento de pasar por allí. Como para ir probando el camino de regreso. Gracias.

Comment: *Perdón por los scripts de javascript. Realmente los puse para ver que saltaran los alert al momento de pasar por allí. Como para ir probando el camino de regreso.* Es que, Ajax no funciona así, Ajax es OTRO concepto. Tú mandas algo desde el cliente al servidor, eso se procesa en el archivo que pongas en el parámetro `url` y luego es `success` revisas la respuesta. Generalmente, eso viene en un json, porque es más fácil organizar las cosas de ese modo y es ligero, por eso se pone `dataType: "json"` en la petición Ajax (otros tipos son posibles) ...

Comment: ... Entonces, no tiene sentido meter un `script` de Javascript en todo ese flujo, porque entre otras cosas tu petición Ajax espera un JSON, y meter otra cosa, va a romper el JSON. Es importante que entiendas eso si vas a usar Ajax. El quid de la cuestión es controlar el código en PHP y devolver a Ajax una respuesta en el formato esperado y verificar esa respuesta según un criterio determinado. Ahora te lo pongo en una respuesta. Pero es importante que entiendas que Ajax no debe ser pensado como los programas antiguos donde para mandar algo y tener respuesta debías recargar la página.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax sirve para comunicar entre cliente y servidor sin necesidad de recargar la página. Es muy simple, tú mandas algo al servidor, todo eso se procesa en el archivo que pongas en el parámetro `url` y devuelves una respuesta conforme al `dataType`. Se suele usar `json` porque es ligero y porque es más simple organizar datos estructurados.

PERO debes controlar el flujo totalmente. Si Ajax espera un JSON no puedes salir por Peteneras en algunas partes del código con cosas como `echo 'No se qué';` o con un bloque de `<script>...</script>`, ni siquiera con contenido `html`, porque el JSON se rompe al ser estructurado. Entonces, lo que hay que hacer es controlar el flujo.

El criterio que seguiremos es simple: cuando haya algún error, meteremos en `$outPut` una entrada con la clave `error` asociada a un mensaje. Cuando no haya error, meteremos en `$outPut` un clave `success`. Y finalmente, devolveremos `$outPut` al cliente, eso devolveremos y nada más, para no romper el flujo.

Veamos:

### `ordenesA.php`

```
$numQuanty =$_POST["numQuanty"] ?? NULL;

if($numQuanty){
    $kantidad=$_POST["kantidad"] ?? 0;
    $IdPedido =$_POST["IdPedido"] ?? 0;
    $Total =$_POST["Total"] ?? 0;
    $idOrden =$_POST["idOrden"] ?? 0;
    $qC = new QuantyChangeA();
    $qC -> kantidad = $kantidad;
    $qC -> idQc     = $IdPedido;
    $qC -> total    = $Total;
    $qC -> numQuanty= $numQuanty;
    $qC -> idOrden  = $idOrden;
    $outPut = $qC -> numQuantyChange();
} else {
    $outPut = array('error'=>'No se posteó valor para numQuanty');
}

/*
   Esta es la ÚNICA  salida
   que debe tener tu código, NADA más
   por lo ya dicho: Ajax espera un JSON y nada más
*/

header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
echo json_encode($outPut);
```

---

### Clase `QuantyChangeA`

Simplemente retornaremos el resultado de la llamada a `OrdenesC::cambiarCantidadC()` y punto.

```
class QuantyChangeA{

    public $kantidad;
    public $idQc;
    public $total;
    public $numQuanty;
    public $idOrden;

    public function numQuantyChange(){
    
        $Q = $this->kantidad;
        $I = $this->idQc;
        $T = $this->total; 
        $O = $this->idOrden;
        return OrdenesC::cambiarCantidadC($Q, $I, $T, $O);
    }

}
```

---

### La función `cambiarCantidadM`

Cambia profundamente. En ella vamos a controlar todo lo que pueda fallar, mandando siempre un array con clave `error` o `success` como ya dije más arriba.

```
static public function cambiarCantidadM($tablaBD, $Q, $I, $T){
    $pdo = ConexionBD::cBD();
    if ($pdo) {
        if ($stmt=$pdo->prepare("UPDATE $tablaBD SET cantidad = :cantidad, p_total = :total WHERE id = :id")) {
            $stmt -> bindParam(":cantidad", $Q, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt -> bindParam(":total", $T, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt -> bindParam(":id", $I, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            if( $stmt -> execute() ){
                $msg=sprintf("Filas actualizadas: %d",$stmt->rowCount());
                return array('success'=>$msg);
            } else {
                return array('error'=>'No se ejecutó la consulta');
            }
        } else {
            return array('error'=>'Falló la preparación de la consulta');
        }
    } else {
        return array('error'=>'No hay conexión');
    }
}
```

### Petición Ajax en el cliente

Finalmente, en el cliente, vas a consumir la respuesta de este modo (revisa la parte del `then`, puse unos `alert` sólo a modo de depuración, luego los quitas):

```
    success: function(resultado){
        swal({
            title: 'Cantidad ha cambiado.',
            type: 'success',
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            confirmButtonText: 'Aceptar' 
        }).then(function(resultado){
            if(resultado.success){
                alert(resultado.success);
                window.location = "http://localhost/restaurante/index.php?url=Orden&MN="+mesaId+"&Oid="+ordenId;
            } else {
                /*Hubo error, lanza tu política de errore*/
                alert(resultado.error);
            }
        });
    }
```

Con este código he implementado todo lo que traté de explicarte más arriba y en comentarios. Con esto debería resolverse. Si no entiendes algo pregunta en un comentario, al pie de esta respuesta. Y, una vez aprendida la lección, tenlo en cuenta cada vez que uses Ajax o la API Fetch de Javascript. Te ahorrarás muuuuuchas horas y muchos dolores de cabeza.

Comment: Nuevamente muchas gracias A. Cedano. Todo está claro y comprendido. Me has dado más que ayuda, una masterclass. He comprendido la logica de tu código y ahora lo implementaré y haré los ajustes para que funcione en mi aplicación. Estaré confirmando el éxito.

Comment: Todo funcionó bien. Ya estoy logrando una respuesta al ajax y funciona con todas las validaciones agregadas. Gracias A. Celano.
Solo debo repasar y entender mas el manejo de ese objeto string que viene como respuesta.